# MQTT can not connect to Apollo server

Tags: ruby, mqtt, apollo

After download the Apollo from official website and install in Mac OS X 10.10.2, as the topic said form [Apollo 1.7 MQTT Protocol Manual](http://activemq.apache.org/apollo/documentation/mqtt-manual.html), i set the connector for mqtt in *apache-apollo-1.7/bin/androidMQ/etc/apollo.xml*:

`<connector id="tcp" bind="tcp://0.0.0.0:61613" protocol="mqtt"/>`

and then created a broker(androidMQ) and run:

```
androidMQ/bin/apollo-broker run
```

the log like this:

```
$ androidMQ/bin/apollo-broker run

    _____                .__  .__
   /  _  \ ______   ____ |  | |  |   ____
  /  /_\  \\____ \ /  _ \|  | |  |  /  _ \
 /    |    \  |_> >   )  |_|  |_(   )
 \____|__  /   __/ \____/|____/____/\____/
         \/|__|  Apache Apollo (1.7)


Loading configuration file '/Users/jijin/services/apache-apollo-1.7/bin/androidMQ/etc/apollo.xml'.
INFO  | OS     : Mac OS X 10.10.2
INFO  | JVM    : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_65 (Apple Inc.)
INFO  | Apollo : 1.7 (at: /Users/jijin/services/apache-apollo-1.7)
INFO  | OS is restricting the open file limit to: 6250
INFO  | Starting store: leveldb store at /Users/jijin/services/apache-apollo-1.7/bin/androidMQ/data
INFO  | Accepting connections at: tcp://0.0.0.0:61613
INFO  | Administration interface available at: https://127.0.0.1:61681/
INFO  | Administration interface available at: http://127.0.0.1:61680/`
```

then,i used it with ruby gem : [ruby-mqtt](https://github.com/njh/ruby-mqtt)
and my script are:

subsctibe.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mqtt'
MQTT::Client.connect("localhost", 1883) do |client|
  client.get("test") do |topic, message|
    puts "#{topic}---content: #{message}\n"
  end
end
```

publish.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mqtt'
MQTT::Client.connect("localhost", 1883) do |c|
  c.publish("test", "gogogo!")
end
```

when i run it, the error ：

```
$ ruby lib/mqtt/apollo_subscribe.rb
/Users/jijin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/mqtt-0.3.1/lib/mqtt/client.rb:496:in `block in receive_connack': Connection refused: bad user name or password (MQTT::ProtocolException)
    from /Users/jijin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:69:in `timeout'
    from /Users/jijin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/mqtt-0.3.1/lib/mqtt/client.rb:486:in `receive_connack'
    from /Users/jijin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/mqtt-0.3.1/lib/mqtt/client.rb:277:in `connect'
    from /Users/jijin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/mqtt-0.3.1/lib/mqtt/client.rb:93:in `connect'
    from lib/mqtt/apollo_subscribe.rb:4:in `'
```

when i changed the host and port to:

```
MQTT::Client.connect("test.mosquitto.org", 1883)
```

the test is ok, but when i changed the host to localhost and no matter i changed the port to 1883 or 61613, the error happend.
i don't know what to do now.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it seems that nobody got to help me, I repeatedly see apollo.xml this configuration file, accidentally gave it to solve. Uncomment to disable security for the virtual host，

`<!-- Uncomment to disable security for the virtual host -->`

`<authentication enabled="false"/>`

maybe i should read the configuration more carefully.